# Identify Geographic features by clicking on published map (ArcGIS Server)

Tags: arcgis-server, postgresql, json

I have a published map on ArcGIS Server. My map is accessing traffic signals data  from a table in PostgreSQL. I am trying to display feature properties by clicking on any traffic light.

Solved!

Comment: What have you tried? There are tons of samples out there that do this. For example http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=find_drilldown

Comment: I am still trying to find some way. my employer wants me to display data on ArcGIS server(Published map) and I think in the Sandbox we access the published map and display it on ArcGIS Online. am I right? Is there any possibility to replace .json file located in server?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Please clarify by editing your question (it is better than writing it in a comment). The sample I provided uses an ArcGIS Server published map service (not a .json file). It is NOT on arcgisonline. It is simply running it in their sandbox application. Code that runs there can also run on your web server.

Comment: I think I am doing it wrong way.Let me try to do it again. Thank you